# Script (or conf file modification) for putty on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, script, regedit

How can i add a script to putty for windows?
I found many links describing the procedure but all them are for Linux.
I would like to change the color of the router/device names during ssh.

Regards.

Comment: perhaps you should link to the linux one so people can look at it and look for a windows equivalent. Also bear in mind that some SSH servers for windows will give a bash prompt and others will give a `c:\` prompt. So openssh server in cygwin will give a bash prompt. But winsshd gives a 1c:\` prompt and that may make  a difference. So state which server you use so we know wether you get a `$` or `C:\`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I am using the router's ip and doing ssh direct to the device.
I am logging in to several devices every day as i am working for a telco company.
Maybe i was not correct when i asked about "script" - perhaps the persons that use Putty in linux are just editing a conf file - my question is where to find this conf file to edit it for windows users.

For example:
http://s0.cyberciti.org/uploads/faq/2006/10/bash-adding-colors-to-ps1-prompt.png

Taken from this link:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/


Regards

Comment: ok that linux command changing the variable, to change prompt colour, isn't really to do with putty or the fact that you're logging into a router. It is just how to change colours in the current terminal in linux.  MSDOS used to have a way of doing this with loading ANSI.SYS in config.SYS and using so-called ansi escape sequences that looked like `prompt $e[....$p$g`   But Windows doesn't have that natively, it seems. There is this hack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297072/color-for-the-prompt-just-the-prompt-proper-in-cmd-exe-and-powershell  But I don't think that will work from ssh.

Comment: the hack I linked to creates a patched cmd that supports ansi escape sequences.  so I suppose won't work in an ssh session .

Comment: i've used putty and cygwin openssh, but I haven't tried either putty or cygwin openssh in relation to changing colurs,  but your router is linux so what if you use cygwin ssh client, instead of putty.